# Spock - Test Events Not Received, "NO-SOURCE"

Tags: groovy, spock

I am getting an error `"test events not received"` when trying to run a basic Spock Test within my IDE.  The issue seems to be due to `:test NO-SOURCE`.  What am I missing?

Gradle output:

```
C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\schema-test>gradlew :cleanTest :test --tests com.scarlatti.SpockTest
:cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Project structure:

```
src
├───main
│   └───groovy
│      └───com
│          └───scarlatti
│               └───App.java
└───test
    └───groovy
        └───com
            └───scarlatti
                    SpockTest.groovy
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2'
}
```

Simple Spock test:

```
class SpockTest extends Specification {
    @Test
    "test that a spock test will run"() {
        when:
            println "running spock test..."
        then:
            notThrown(Exception)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your `build.gradle` file.

Notice from the output that Gradle is only running the task `:compileJava`, but not `:compileGroovy`.

Spock test classes are written in Groovy, so no class `com.scarlatti.SpockTest` will be built unless you tell Gradle to run task `:compileGroovy` on build.

Solution:

- include `apply plugin: 'groovy'` in `build.gradle`.  This will attach the `:compileGroovy` task to Gradle's `:test` task graph.
- include the `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.x` jar in your compile dependencies.  This allows Gradle to compile the Groovy code.  Match the version of groovy to the version of Spock you are using.

Comment: `groovy-all` dependency does not have to be added explicitly - adding `spock-core` is enough, valid `groovy-all` will be added automatically.

Comment: I get _org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: configuration ':compileClasspath'_ when not including explicit groovy dependency.